# how do you setup a db data source in a visual studio 2005 deployment

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, dsn

I'm working on deploying a visual studio 2005 windows application executable with an embedded crystal report using visual basic.  It seems to install everything just fine, however, the system dsn isn't being setup.

How do you configure a setup project to setup the system dsn during the installation?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [custom action](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/0aab7af6-3576-41ae-9df4-29943e6986ad) to create your DSN